# Need help correcting error message

Tags: errors, texmaker

I've been trying to run this on TexMaker but keep getting this error message when I try to compile the tex document to pdf:

```
Error : could not start the command : pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "Student Handbook 2020-2021".tex
```

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Have you an TeX distribution like MiKTeX or TeX Live installed?

Comment: that is not a tex error it is an operating system error saying the command is not found, so either you have not installed tex or it is not where you have configured texmaker to fid it. If you type that error message into the site's search box you will find dozens of answers related to this.

Comment: @Bernard since it's not finding tex you can use `foobar` as a complete code example, and would get the same error.